# why can't I pass an unassigned object variable in an out parameter and then assign it

Tags: c#, out-parameters

In C#, why can't I pass an unassigned object variable in an `out` parameter and then assign it?

If I try to do this, there is a compiler error: *"Local variable `<xyz>` cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to `<xyz>`..."*

eg.

```
void MyMethod(int x, out MyObject mo) {  **MyObject** mo = new MyObject(); }
// in some other scope:
MyObject mo;
MyMethod(1, out mo);
```

EDIT: I can see my mistake now. I have changed the above code to what mine was. The `MyObject` in asterisks should not be there.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted (except the semi-colon in the parameter list, which I assume is a typo). Please post the *exact* code that is generating this error.

Comment: Try a comma between parameters instead of a semi-colon, though I expect that's just a typo.

Comment: Try using the `under` keyword instead.

Comment: @Dean: submit an answer and I will award it.

Comment: There *is* no `under` keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you posted original was incorrect, but now we see that the problem is actually here:

```
void MyMethod(int x, out MyObject mo)
{
    MyObject mo = new MyObject();
    // should be:
    // mo = new MyObject();
}
```

You're creating a new local variable `mo` which "hides" the parameter `mo`.

Glad we got there in the end :-)

Answer (score 2):

This error message means that there is another variable named `mo` somewhere in the same method. For example, such code would cause this error:

```
for( int mo = 0; i < 5; i++ ) Console.WriteLine( mo );

MyObject mo;
```

You probably didn't think it was related, so you didn't post the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation

[out (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx(VS.80).aspx)

> The out keyword causes arguments to be
>   passed by reference. This is similar
>   to the ref keyword, except that ref
>   requires that the variable be
>   initialized before being passed. To
>   use an out parameter, both the method
>   definition and the calling method must
>   explicitly use the out keyword.
>
> **Although variables passed as an out arguments need not be initialized
>   prior to being passed, the calling
>   method is required to assign a value
>   before the method returns.**

So it should be fine, except that your method syntax is incorrect. You need to use a comma instead of a semi colon to seperate parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Given your actual code, you cannot define mo because it's already defined as an out parameter